# Workout Plan model with Days and Exercises using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I would like to be able to create Workout Plan for the gym using Ruby on Rails. A Workout Plan would consist of a name, he would have X number of days which would have X number of exercises.

This is what a Workout Plan would look like

Name: **Beginner Workout**

- Day 1
  - Exercise 1
  - Exercise 2
  - Exercise 3
- Day 2
  - Exercise 1
  - Exercise 2
- Day 3
  - Exercise 1
  - Exercise 2
  - Exercise 3
  - Exercise 4

Now the exercises would come from a given pool (entered by me), where the user can choose from (by Checkboxes).

This is what a simplified form would look like to create a new Workout Plan:

[image: New Workout Plan Form]

I am ok for now having a fixed amount of days and adding days dynamically would be my next step but for now it is not important.

Right now i have 3 Models. Plan, PlanDay and Exercise. The relations are

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: plans
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :plan_days

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :plan_days
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: plan_days
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class PlanDay < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: exercises
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :plan_days
end
```

I really can't get near a form like the above and i think my relations are maybe not right. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a screencast by Ryan Bates which is almost exactly what i need http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

Review your modelling:

1. For Days. I don't think this is a necessary model. It can simply integrated into a field in exercise. An exercise can be on, and only on a certain calendar day.
2. You should not use has_and_belongs_to_many relationship here. An exercise must belong to a certain plan, that's simple.
3. Something should be related to customer. I prefer using Plan. Then Exercises are related to Plan only.

Now let's try to model again

```
# Customer has many Plans
Model: Plan
  - Name
  - Start(date)
  - End(date)
  - Customer(id)

# Plan has many exercises
Model: Exercise
  - Name
  - Date
  - Plan(id)
```

Showing daily arrangements is easy under this model. For example, if you want to show exercises in day one, you can just search the exercises under this plan and the date is on first day or this plan.